# Full body detection and tracking using OpenCV+Python-2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, object-detection

There are a lot of materials available to do this with C++. I would to know if there is a way to do full body detection using OpenCV in Python-2.7?

Given video of a person walking along the sagittal plane (camera taken 90 degrees from the direction of walk), I would like to bound a region of interest rectangle covering the entire body of that person and track the same in movement frame by frame.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @M4rtini: Thanks for the info; I've added the details. I am searching for a feasible solution for the problem not for study material.

Comment: Have to tried detecting it with haar cascades??  there are haar cascades for full body detection https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_fullbody.xml

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee: That's exactly what I'm having trouble with. I just thought someone might have this fixed or have a simpler solution without it.

Comment: What trouble exactly you are having?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee, It just doesn't recognize properly, a whole lot of both false negatives and false positives. here are the params. if it helps: `detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=1, minSize(20,40), flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE)` I tried experimenting with different values too. It didn't help.

Comment: can you update the question with some screenshots of the video you want to track from?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee: Sorry, I can't do that; the data is licensed. To simply put it, its a video of a person moving from right to left with an *almost* static background.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This one is using the hog descriptor you can find the sample in samples/python/peopledetect.py I used the sample video provided by the opencv installation.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


def inside(r, q):
    rx, ry, rw, rh = r
    qx, qy, qw, qh = q
    return rx > qx and ry > qy and rx + rw < qx + qw and ry + rh < qy + qh


def draw_detections(img, rects, thickness = 1):
    for x, y, w, h in rects:
        # the HOG detector returns slightly larger rectangles than the real objects.
        # so we slightly shrink the rectangles to get a nicer output.
        pad_w, pad_h = int(0.15*w), int(0.05*h)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x+pad_w, y+pad_h), (x+w-pad_w, y+h-pad_h), (0, 255, 0), thickness)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
    hog.setSVMDetector( cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector() )
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture('vid.avi')
    while True:
        _,frame=cap.read()
        found,w=hog.detectMultiScale(frame, winStride=(8,8), padding=(32,32), scale=1.05)
        draw_detections(frame,found)
        cv2.imshow('feed',frame)
        ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1)
        if ch == 27:
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

## Results

Not so good. Still give it a try 
 [image]

Comment: You did it! It works like a charm for the video of my constraints. I see you've implemented Histogram of Gradients. Could you also provide any links so I could learn more of your code?

Comment: It was in the samples of opencv python . HOG is a feature descriptor  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients basically these stuff is an more complex version of http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_svm/py_svm_opencv/py_svm_opencv.html . here they do the same thing for hand identifying hand written digits and here the object is more complex . You can search more on HoG descriptor and SVM on google

Comment: Function `inside` is used to determine whethear rectangle r is inside of rectangle q. There is an algorithm called []non-maxima suppression](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/) to solve the problem that take multiple, overlapping bounding boxes and reduce them to only a single bounding box.

Comment: How can we improve accuracy? In my video it detects hands and lower body too