# Better Human detection from a UAV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on a project wherein I am supposed to detect human beings from a live video stream which I get from a UAV's camera module. I do not need to create any rectangles or boxes around detected subjects, but just need to reply with a yes or no. I am fairly new to Open-CV and have no prior experience.

**What I have tried:**

I started by training my SVM on HOG features. My team gathered a few images from a UAV we had, with people in it. I then trained the SVM from the crops of those people. We got unsatisfactory results when we used the trained detector on the  a video from sky with people. Moreover processing each frame turned out to be very slow , therefore the system became unusable.(it did work on still images to some extent).

**My question:**

I wanted to know if there is some other technique, library etc I could try for achieving good results. Please point me to the next step.

Comment: "My team gathered a few images from a UAV" - for successful hog training you need *hundreds* of images, like from inria person dataset

Comment: You tried the opencv built in hog detector ?? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34873750/3832190 you might take a look at this answer might help you

Comment: @berak from the images we had(50+) we could extract a large ,200+ positives samples of humans. Also we extracted 1000 + neg samples. But detection turned out to be slow, as the camera was giving high res images. Are there any other algorithms that can be used for the same.

Comment: @ Arjit Mukherjee Yes, we used the same. However since humans look different from height(150 feet+), we had to create our own dataset for the training. Opencv doesnot provide detectMultiScale() and some other functions for custom dataset. We thus used svm.predict(). Any other ideas Arjit ?

Comment: This might help you: http://www.geocities.ws/talh_davidc/