# error using HOG descriptor peopledetect.py

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, real-time, webcam

I'm using a Rpi3 with opencv3 on it and a Logitech c170 webcam.

The code I used is from [Full body detection and tracking using OpenCV+Python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871294/full-body-detection-and-tracking-using-opencvpython-2-7)

I changed

`cap=cv2.VideoCapture('vid.avi')`

into

`cap=cv2.VideoCapture('0')`

Bacause I'm working with a real time video stream. 
When I start the script the green ('on') light on my webcam really short flashes and then I get the following error:

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0) in locateROI, file /home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 981
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peopledetect.py", line 25, in <module>
    found,w=hog.detectMultiScale(frame, winStride=(8,8), padding=(32,32), scale=1.05)
cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:981: error: (-215) dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in function locateROI`

I checked and my webcam is on the list that is suitable for a Rpi3.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: try cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0) instead of cap=cv2.VideoCapture('0')

Comment: It worked! but only from the terminal on the Pi. If I try to run it via SSH I get the following error: (process:1168): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
 Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(feed:1168): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Comment: do you use any gui functions (imshow?)? Maybe it will work with x-forwarding, no idea...

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture('0')
```

Into:

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

It work very good.